# Restoring a DB using C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to restore a DB from one server to the other using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo. The issue is I keep getting an error stating that it cannot find the .MDF file. THe reason for that is that it is trying to find it in a the data folder for the Instance name of SQL from whence it came rather than looking in the data folder of another instance of SQL. Is there a way to to tell it which folder to search for the mdf rather than assuming it is the one tagged to the BAK file? This is so frustrating

Comment: What code using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` have you tried? You get the same problem working with Management Studio and have to alter the file location through the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQL_Server_2005_Database.aspx?display=Print) by Bappi M Ahmed. It shows a complete method for restoring a database file. Here is the method it shows:

```
public void RestoreDatabase(String databaseName, String filePath, 
       String serverName, String userName, String password, 
       String dataFilePath, String logFilePath)
{
    Restore sqlRestore = new Restore();

    BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(filePath, DeviceType.File);
    sqlRestore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
    sqlRestore.Database = databaseName;

    ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
    Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

    Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
    sqlRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
    String dataFileLocation = dataFilePath + databaseName + ".mdf";
    String logFileLocation = logFilePath + databaseName + "_Log.ldf";
    db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
    RelocateFile rf = new RelocateFile(databaseName, dataFileLocation);

    sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(databaseName, dataFileLocation));
    sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(databaseName+"_log", logFileLocation));
    sqlRestore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
    sqlRestore.Complete += new ServerMessageEventHandler(sqlRestore_Complete);
    sqlRestore.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;
    sqlRestore.PercentComplete += 
       new PercentCompleteEventHandler(sqlRestore_PercentComplete);

    sqlRestore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
    db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
    db.SetOnline();
    sqlServer.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the bak file keeps pointing to a file path that only existed from where it came from not where I want it to loook on the new server

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to add [`RelocateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.relocatefile.aspx) objects to the [`RelocateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.relocatefiles.aspx) ArrayList Property on the [`Restore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.aspx) object. Have you tried this?

Comment: I tried this but the bak file keeps pointing to a file path that only existed from where it came from not where I want it to loook on the new server

Comment: @Ryan Lege, show us your code please, paticularly the bit surronding where you construct the RelocateFile object.