# Restore SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo, database-restore

I'm trying to restore a SQL database backup with this code

```
private void btnRestore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dbName = "BakodahDB";
    try
    {
        Server dbServer = new Server(); //local using windows athuentication 
        Restore dbRestore = new Restore() { Database = dbName, Action = RestoreActionType.Database, ReplaceDatabase = true, NoRecovery = false };
        dbRestore.Devices.AddDevice(@"C:\WorkHours\dbBackup.bak", DeviceType.File);
        dbRestore.PercentComplete += DbRestore_PercentComplete;
        dbRestore.Complete += DbRestore_Complete;
        dbRestore.SqlRestoreAsync(dbServer);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

When I click the button nothing happens, not even an error message... What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restoring a DB using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943137/restoring-a-db-using-c-sharp)

Comment: In order to further assist, I have a couple of questions. Have you tried moving the `dbRestore` out to a higher scope such as the class? What do your delegates' `DbRestore_PercentComplete` and `DbRestore_Complete` implementations look like? Is it possible that the work is just long running?

Comment: Try the non-async version; does that throw? Alternatively, handle the [`Information`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backuprestorebase.information.aspx) event - anything reported?

Comment: @Cameron just tried it it didn't work, 'DbRestore_PercentComplete' and 'DbRestore_Complete' just updates a progress bar and a status text label.

Comment: @Blorgbeard just tried it, at least now there's an error message `Failed to Restore....` before it was no response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed to kill all process before restoring

```
            // Kill all processes
            dbServer.KillAllProcesses(dbRestore.Database);
            // Set single-user mode
            Database db = dbServer.Databases[dbRestore.Database];
            // db.DatabaseOptions.UserAccess=true;
            db.Alter(TerminationClause.RollbackTransactionsImmediately);
            // Detach database
            dbServer.DetachDatabase(dbRestore.Database, false);
```

it worked!